# Can firbolgs use both spells from Firbolg Magic in the same day, or just one?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, firbolg

Firbolgs have the Firbolg Magic trait (VGtM, p. 107):

> You can cast *detect magic* and *disguise self* with this trait, using
>   Wisdom as your spell casting ability for them. Once you cast either
>   spell, you can't cast it again with this trait until you finish a
>   short or long rest.

Does Firbolg Magic have one use that's expended when either spell is cast? Or does it have two uses, where each spell can be cast once?

Comment: I didn't know the Fir Bolg had made it into RPGs. Cool.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They can cast each spell once per day, so two spells in total. The trick is in the wording:

> Once you cast **either** spell, you can't cast **it** again with this trait until you finish a short or long rest.

Since "either" means "The one or the other" and "it" means "the one previously mentioned" the ability essentially reads:

> Once you cast *one of these spells*, you can't cast *that spell* again with this trait until you finish a short or long rest.

(But honestly, the wording on this trait is rather confusing to me as well. Might be one these cases where my 'not a native English speaker' shines through.)

Comment: The wording was probably skirting the possible interpretation that you could not cast the spell from other sources (firbolgs mages would suck).

Comment: I think the "with this trait" part guards against that quite effectively, but that might have been the reason.